# how to keep blankets from slipping off the bed at night

Tags: bedroom, sleeping

No matter how I make the bed, in the morning all the blankets are on my husbands side of the bed and/or on the floor at the bottom of the bed.

How do I prevent this from happening, and keeping the blankets on the bed?

Answer (score 4):

We buy oversize blankets (e.g. king-size for a queen-sized bed) and tuck them under in [hospital corner](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Hospital-Corner) style. If there are *two* blankets, e.g. a light-weight one covered by a heavy quilt, only the lower blanket needs to be larger, as it keeps the upper in place.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some kind of slippery blankets or cover which is made of satin or nylon. If you use blankets made of cotton or wool they won't slide and will stay on the bed.

Answer (score 0):

what about **fitted sheets**?

> A sheet tailored to form pocket for a mattress with elastic edges that is suitable for a range of mattress sizes. The edge may also contain a drawstring to secure the sheet more firmly and enable use on a wider range of mattress thickness.

(from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fitted_sheet)

Answer (score 0):

The trick that worked was to only tuck in the top sheet, one blanket, and make hospital corners.  With all the blankest tucked under, they still ended up on the floor by morning.  I was surprised that the blankets on top of the one tucked in did not slip. Letting  the top blankets hang over a few inches, may have also helped, because there was less blanket weight pulling down.  Thanks everyone, I would have never thought of tucking in only one blanket.

Comment: This sounds very much like the top answer here, so it would have been better to mark it as accepted answer, and add a comment if you ended up doing something bit different.